# Let $B = \{δ_1,...,δ_n\}$ be subset of $D(V)$ and assume there exists vector $0_V \ne v ∈ V$ satisfying $δ_i(v) = 0$. Show $B$ is linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, determinant

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over a
field $F$. Let $B = \{δ_1,...,δ_n\}$ be a subset of $D(V)$ and assume that there exists a
vector $0_V 
\ne v ∈ V$ satisfying $δ_i(v) = 0$ for all $0 ≤ i ≤ n$. Show that $B$ is linearly
dependent.

I'm not sure how to go about this. Any solutions/hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is $D(V)$?

Comment: The Dual space, probably.

Comment: Consider the linear mapping $T:D(V)\to F$ given by $T(\delta)=\delta(v)$. What could you say about $T$ if you knew that it's kernel had dimension equal to $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $f\colon V\to F^n$ defined by
$$
f(x)=\begin{bmatrix}
\delta_1(x)\\
\vdots\\
\delta_n(x)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and identify $D(F^n)$ with the space of $1\times n$ matrices. Then the transpose of this map is
$$
f^*\colon D(F^n)\to D(V)
$$
defined by
$$
f^*(\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1&\dots&\alpha_n\end{bmatrix})=
\alpha_1\delta_1+\dots+\alpha_n\delta_n
$$
Since $f$ is not an isomorphism, because $f(v)=0$, neither $f^*$ is an isomorphism, so it is not injective.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be linearly independent, $c_1=...=c_n=0$ when $\sum_{i=0}^n c_i \delta_i(v)=0$. Evaluating each $c_i \delta_i=c_i=0$ (based on the given condition that $\delta_i(v)=0$  $\forall v \in V$), we see that $B$ must be linearly independent.

Comment: Also, because the $dim(V)=n$ (and we have $n$ $\delta$'s), $B$ also spans $D(V)$, thus forming a basis.