# Proving that if $p_j(2)=0$ for every $j$ then $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_n$ is not linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

**Question**: Let $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_m\in P_m(F)$ such that $p_j(2)=0$ for $j=1,\dots,m$. Prove that $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_m$ are not linearly independent in $P_m(F)$.

Here $F$ denotes the field of real or complex numbers.

**Proof**: Note that $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_m$ is linearly independent if and only if for every $z\in F$ $a_0p_0(z)+\dots+a_mp_m(z)=0\implies a_0=\dots=a_m=0$. Given that $p_j(2)=0$, pick non-zero scalars $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_m\in F$. Then we have that $$c_1p_0(2)+\dots+c_mp_m(2)=0$$ This shows that $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_m$ is linearly dependent and thus not linearly independent.

Am I missing some subtle in this exercise or is this proof correct?

**Edit**: Throughout the whole proof I was referring to the number $0\in F$ and not the zero polynomial.

Comment: You have shown that $c_0 p_0 + \cdots + c_n p_n$ takes the value $0$ at $2$, but this is not the same as saying $c_0 p_0 + \cdots + c_n p_n$ is the zero polynomial!

Comment: @TheoBendit Should I prove that there exist non-zero scalars $c_0,\dots,c_n$ such that $c_0p_0(2)+\dots+c_np_n(2)=0$ where $0\in F$. Or should I prove that there exist non-zero scalars $c_0,\dots,c_n$ such that $c_0p_0+\dots+c_np_n\equiv 0$ where $0$ denotes the $0$ polynomial?

Comment: The first condition is immediate from the hypotheses but that's not the definition of linear dependence. The definition of linear dependence is the second thing you wrote, so that's what you need to prove. A hint: try actually writing down an example of such a collection of polynomials.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks! I'll try to prove that.

Comment: I don't believe the assertion in the question. For example, if $n=0$ it seems even more unlikely. (Or is it intended that $m=n$?)

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for pointing that out. I actually just realized I had written the question wrong. $n$ was indeed supposed to be $m$.

Comment: If $\{p_0,...,p_m\}$ is linearly independent it would form a basis for an $m+1$ dimensional subspace of $P_m$. But $P_m$ itself has dimension $m+1$ so independence implies $\{p_0,...,p_m\}$ spans all of $P_m$. Why is this not possible?

Comment: @MatthewH. Sorry for the late reply but I just saw it. Thanks for the help. I get it. Because if it spans $P_m$, then the polynomial defined by $p(z)=2$ should be able to be written as a linear combination of the list $p_0,\dots,p_m$ but it can't as $c_0p_0(2)+\dots+c_mp_m(2)\ne p(2)$. Again, Thanks a lot!