# Reference request: linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I'm looking for a linear algebra textbook with some specific features and I hope you can help me with your recommendations. The kind of textbook I'm looking for is:

- A book that starts from the basics, or at least has an introduction of the basics of LA, but extends deep into the subject. By that, I mean that it covers the contents of at least 2-3 university courses on Linear Algebra.
- Easy to understand and hopefully with lots of visual aids (for example, featuring image examples for the SVD decomposition. That sort of thing).
- If possible with solved exercises and a section with the most important proofs.

Do you know a book close to these specs?

Btw: if you know a really good textbook that doesn't exactly adhere to these criteria, please, recommend it anyway.

Thanks

Comment: Hey! Welcome to math stack exchange. I personally use (actually using) Hoffman and Kunze linear algebra text book.

Comment: I would recommend the textbook: Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler. It’s really well written and starts with basics. First builds the theory of vector spaces and then moves onto linear maps. Develops the theory of linear maps and then moves onto eigenvalues, eigenvectors, inner product spaces and all the other things you’re looking for. Here are two chapters available for free to read on the authors website. [Table of contents](https://linear.axler.net/Contents.pdf), [Chapter 5](https://linear.axler.net/Eigenvalues.pdf), [Chapter 6](https://linear.axler.net/InnerProduct.pdf).

Comment: @Seeker I kind of agree with your comment. I mostly like problems from linear algebra done right by Axler book. Some problems are extremely easy/few liner and some problems are decent “conventional” problems. I would really appreciate if you can share which problems from chapter 2 & 3 are “good” in your opinion. By good, I mean everyone should try to approach those problems.

Comment: @user264745 I generally try to do all of the problems. But here are a few that stood out, were difficult than the others and I used many times in other places. Chapter 2: There aren’t that many difficult problems in each section of this chapter. Maybe like 2 every section. So I’d recommend just doing all of them. One exercise I used again from this section was exercise $14$ from section $2.A$. It’s a basic exercise that gives a criteria for when a vector space is infinite dimensional. As for a difficult exercise: exercise $17$, section $2.A$ was difficult for me.

Comment: @user264745 All the exercises in section $2.B$ are doable and I think everyone should do them. For section $2.C$: Most exercises aren’t that hard I’m this section. But there are $4$ in the beginning that ask you to find a basis of subspaces of $P_m(F)$ ant I found these a little difficult at the time. But it was really good practice. Now moving onto chapter $3$: I would highly recommend understanding the very first theorem proved in this section. That theorem is by far the most used theorem within chapter $3$. The theorem is that a linear map can take on any value on its basis.

Comment: @user264745 It took me a while to understand the importance of this theorem. It’s used pretty much every time you need to prove some linear map exists(I remember you telling me that. Eventually I saw how much I used it to show existence of linear maps). Definitely do the following exercises in section $3.A$: 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14. Some of these exercises introduce to basic theorems and some tend to be really useful later on. A few of these are also hard first time attempting them. Again for anyone else reading, make sure you do the other problems as well. They’re not that hard.

Comment: @user264745 But they do help build intuition and give you practice. Exercises in section $3.B$: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19. Some of these help build intuition, some are nice exercises and very useful. There are actually many more in this section but I didn’t do the last few problems. Exercises for section $3.C$: All of them. It’s the easiest section of problems in the entire book probably. Exercises for section $3.D$: 1, 2, 3(makes use of an exercise from earlier section), 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20. There are exercises which I found hard and couldn’t do.

Comment: @user264745 Especially exercises: 4, 5 and 6. Exercises for section $3.E$: I’d recommend doing a lot of them. I don’t exactly recall much of what did in this section but I do remember trying to do a lot of them. One problem I’d recommend definitely looking at is exercise $3$. I was not able to do it after a lot of thinking. Exercises for section $3.F$: I do not recall much of the exact exercises I did in this chapter. There are a lot of useful theorems proved in this chapter. But I’d recommend just attempting a lot of them. Some are easy, some help build intuition and some I just gave up on.

Comment: @Seeker yup exercise 4 of section 2.A is few liner if one knows some properties of finite dimensional vector space. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4529128/861687) is my generic proof of exercise 17. IMO this exercise is short and “tricky”. IMO whole Axler’s book is consist of short & tricky problems. In that problem also I used imp theorem to construct a linear map! IMO in general example/application kind of problems are little bit hard. Ex 4 of section 3.A is straightforward and easy. I remember doing ex 7, it’s bit “tricky” to get exact desired result, again it is short & tricky.

Comment: @Seeker Ex 8,9 are nice examples problem. When I saw ex 10, first thing I notice $U\neq V$ and $S\neq 0$, then used these facts to get contradiction. I like this problem. Ex 11, 13 are easy, uses imp theorem. If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector space, then dim$(L(V,W))=\text{dim}(V)\text{dim}(W)$. This is generalize result of ex 12. Ex 14 is nice but requires little bit of try and error. Which point wanna map to which point, basically how one wants to construct linear map. I’m skipping problems of section 3.B. Btw do you know alternative proof of $(AB)C=A(BC)$? use matrix linear trans

Comment: @user264745 Do you mean a proof using the transpose of the matrix? I just used the definition of matrix multiplication to show that $((AB)C)_{j,k}=(A(BC))_{j,k}$. Or alternatively, let $A, B$ and $C$ be matrices of some linear maps $T, S$ and U. Then because  function composition is associative , we have that $M(T(SU))=M((TS)U)$ where $M$ is the linear map that takes a linear map to its matrix. Edit: I meant to write associate and not commutative.

Comment: @Seeker Yes I meant using function associative property to show associative property of matrices. From section 3.B I liked exercise 12. It’s proof is consequences of theorem 2.34. I agree some exercise in section 3.D are bit hard and require some time to solve the problem. Since I haven’t done product and quotients vector space, I can’t expect to do exercise. Most exercise in section 3.F are easy. Easy because some exercises are theorems in Hoffman and Kunze book. Thank you for your recommendation of problems. I really appreciate it.